# Grabbing a innertext from html-element?

Tags: android, title

tthis is my current code:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String result = "";

while ((result = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(result);
    if (result.contains("<title>")) {
        webtitle.setText(result.intern());
    }
}
```

Now, what I currently get in my TextView is:

```
<title>This is the website's title</title>
```

What I want is:

```
This is the website's title
```

What do i need to change to grab what would be called the InnerText of the HtmlElement?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using an XML or HTML parser?

Comment: use jsoup for parsing html tags

Comment: I have absolutly no idea. I have just started learning Android programming at school. They want us to know about the low-level operations.

I use whatever the first solution that works happens to be.. And then I look for improvements later.

Comment: Jsoup, where can I learn about that? I don't know how to use most stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String result = "";

while ((result = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(result);
    if (result.contains("<title>")) {
        String tmp = result.intern();
        int start = tmp.indexOf('>');
        webtitle.setText(tmp.substring(start+1,tmp.substring(start).indexOf('<'));
    }
}
```